# getting Dynamic attribute for element in Jaxb

Tags: java, jaxb

I have the following XML tag with many attributes. The number/name of the attributes is not given because I am getting the XML in runtime and I just know the name of the tag.
How can I use JAXB to get all the attribute as a `Map<String, String>`?

How can I add this to the following Java code:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "script ")
@XmlAccessorType(javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class SearchScriptElement
{

    @XmlAttribute(name = "script")
    private String script = "";

    public String getScript()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setScript(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

XML example:
I can have many attributes that aren't known in runtime:

```
<ScriptList>
    <script name="xxx" value="sss" id=100 >
    <script>
    <script name="xxx" value="sss" id=100 alias="sss">
    <script>
</ScriptList>
```

Comment: please post an example of your XML. This will help to understand your question exactly.

Comment: That question was already asked several times. If you have varying XML structure the only solution is `@XmlAnyElement`. See [JAXB take all content of element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7736678), [JAXB - marshal object with XML string property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958645).

Answer (score 6):

You can do:

```
@XmlAnyAttribute
private Map<QName, String> attributes;
```

Almost the `Map<String, String>` that you wanted.

Answer (score -1):

Create 2 classes `ScriptList` and `Script`:

```
@XmlType(name = "ScriptList")
public class ScriptList {
    private Collection<Script> scripts;

    @XmlElement(name = "location")
    public Collection<Script> getSripts() {
        return scripts;
    }
}

@XmlType(name = "script")
public class Script {
    private String name;
    private String value;
    private String id;
    private String alias;

    @XmlAttribute(name="name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    // add similar getters for value, id, alias.
    // add setters for all fields.
}
```

I believe, that's all. At least this can be your starting point.

Comment: Hi
Thanks for your reply, the issue that i don;t know the attribute of the xml elements during coding so therefore i am asking if i can get it in runtime with no need to know the name of the attributes.

Comment: This is not answering OPs question. OP is asking if they can get a map of attributes where they don't know the names in compile time.