# How can I make a class field become a tag name using JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am using Java and JAXB for XML processing.

I have the following class:

```
public class Characteristic {

    private String characteristic;
    private String value;

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getCharacteristic() {
        return characteristic;
    }

    public void setCharacteristic(String characteristic) {
        this.characteristic = characteristic;
    }

    @XmlValue
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Characteristic c = new Characteristic();
    c.setCharacteristic("store_capacity");
    c.setValue(40);
    Characteristic c2 = new Characteristic();
    c2.setCharacteristic("number_of_doors");
    c2.setValue(4);
}
```

This is the result that I get:

```
<characteristics characteristic="store_capacity">40</characteristics>
<characteristics characteristic="number_of_doors">4</characteristics>
```

I want to get the following result:

```
<store_capacity>40</store_capacity>
<number_of_doors>4</number_of_doors>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Where's [Blaise Doughan](http://www.bdoughan.com/#my-linkedin) when you need him?

Comment: I am curious though as to why you are not satisfied with having the characteristic as an attribute as it would seem to me to be the best fit for representing this data in an XML file.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - Better late than never? http://stackoverflow.com/a/26384827/383861 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/26385563/383861

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of [@XmlElementRef](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElementRef.html) and [JAXBElement](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBElement.html) to produce dynamic element names.

The idea is:

- Make `Characteristic` a subclass of `JAXBElement` and override the `getName()` method to return the name based on the `characteristic` property.
- Annotate `characteristics` with `@XmlElementRef`.
- Provide the `@XmlRegistry` (`ObjectFactory`) with an `@XmlElementDecl(name = "characteristic")`.

Below is a [working test](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/blob/master/runtime/src/test/java/org/hisrc/xml/bind/tests/dynamicelementname/DynamicElementNameTest.java).

The test itself (nothing special):

```
@Test
public void marshallsDynamicElementName() throws JAXBException {
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
    final Characteristics characteristics = new Characteristics();
    final Characteristic characteristic = new Characteristic(
            "store_capacity", "40");
    characteristics.getCharacteristics().add(characteristic);
    context.createMarshaller().marshal(characteristics, System.out);
}
```

Produces:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<characteristics><store_capacity>40</store_capacity></characteristics>
```

Let's start with the `characteristics` root element class. It has a `characteristics` property which is annotated with `@XmlElementRef`. This means that the contents should be either `JAXBElement`s or `@XmlRootElement`-annotated class instances.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "characteristics")
public class Characteristics {

    private final List<Characteristic> characteristics = new LinkedList<Characteristic>();

    @XmlElementRef(name = "characteristic")
    public List<Characteristic> getCharacteristics() {
        return characteristics;
    }

}
```

In order for this to work you also need an `ObjectFactory` or something annotated with `@XmlRegistry` having a corresponding `@XmlElementDecl`:

```
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    @XmlElementDecl(name = "characteristic")
    public JAXBElement<String> createCharacteristic(String value) {
        return new Characteristic(value);
    }

}
```

Recall, the `characteristics` property must contain either `@XmlRootElement`-annotated class instances or `JAXBElement`s. `@XmlRootElement` is not suitable since it's static. But `JAXBElement` is dynamic. You can subclass `JAXBElement` and override the `getName()` method:

```
public class Characteristic extends JAXBElement<String> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final QName NAME = new QName("characteristic");

    public Characteristic(String value) {
        super(NAME, String.class, value);
    }

    public Characteristic(String characteristic, String value) {
        super(NAME, String.class, value);
        this.characteristic = characteristic;
    }

    @Override
    public QName getName() {
        final String characteristic = getCharacteristic();
        if (characteristic != null) {
            return new QName(characteristic);
        }
        return super.getName();
    }

    private String characteristic;

    @XmlTransient
    public String getCharacteristic() {
        return characteristic;
    }

    public void setCharacteristic(String characteristic) {
        this.characteristic = characteristic;
    }
}
```

In this case I've overridden the `getName()` method to dynamically determine the element name. If `characteristic` property is set, its value will be used as the name, otherwise the method opts to the default `characteristic` element.

The code of the test is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/blob/master/runtime/src/test/java/org/hisrc/xml/bind/tests/dynamicelementname/DynamicElementNameTest.java).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [**EclipseLink MOXy**](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) as your [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) provider then you can leverage our `@XmlVariableNode` extension for this use case (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/06/moxys-xmlvariablenode-json-schema.html):

### Java Model

**Characteristics**

We will leverage the `@XmlVariableNode` extension here.  This annotation specifies a field/property from the reference class to be used as the element name.

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlVariableNode;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Characteristics {

    @XmlVariableNode("characteristic")
    private List<Characteristic> characteristics;

}
```

**Characteristic**

We need to mark the `characteristic` field/property as `@XmlTransient` so it won't appear as a child element.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Characteristic {

    @XmlTransient
    private String characteristic;

    @XmlValue
    private String value;

}
```

**jaxb.properties**

To specify MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to have EclipseLink on your classpath and include a file called `jaxb.properties` with the following content in the same package as your domain model (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html).

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

### Demo Code

**Demo**

Here is some demo code that will read/write the desired XML.  Note how the standard JAXB APIs are used.

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Characteristics.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("input.xml");
        Characteristics characteristics = (Characteristics) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(characteristics, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<characteristics>
   <store_capacity>40</store_capacity>
   <number_of_doors>4</number_of_doors>
</characteristics>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can specify your class as :

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Characteristic")
public class Characteristic {


    @XmlElement(name = "store_capacity")
    protected String storeCapacity;


    @XmlElement(name = "number_of_doors")
    protected String numberOfDoors;

    /** getters and setters of above attributes **/
}
```

**EDIT** : If you wants the attributes to be dynamic then you can refer below link

[getting Dynamic attribute for element in Jaxb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656416/getting-dynamic-attribute-for-element-in-jaxb)

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I don't want to limit the user to only two characteristics (storeCapacity and numberOfDoors).

Comment: you can add other attributes as per your requirement in your class. right ?

Comment: The thing is that I will extract the data from a database and I don't want to change the class Characteristic. I mean, a user can add 10 characteristics in database and I will have only two, or three. I can't know the number of characteristics the user will want.

Comment: You mean to say attributes are dynamic. It could be any , Right ?

Comment: Yes, they are dynamic.

Comment: i have update my answer with the link which can help you to create attributes dynamically.

Comment: I'm not sure that the linked to question is relevant as he's trying to create element tag names dynamically, not attributes.

Answer (score 1):

The following approach will work with any [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation.

### Java Model

**Characteristics**

We will leverage an `XmlAnyElement` annotation.  This annotation gives us alot of flexibility on what type of data can be held, including DOM nodes.  We will use an `XmlAdapter` to convert instances of `Characteristic` to DOM nodes.

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Characteristics {

    @XmlAnyElement
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CharacteristicAdapter.class)
    private List<Characteristic> characteristics;

}
```

**Characteristic**

As far as JAXB is concerned this class is no longer part of our model.

```
public class Characteristic {

    String characteristic;

    String value;

}
```

**CharacteristicAdapter**

This `XmlAdapter` converts the `Characteristic` object to and from a DOM node allowing us to construct it as we like.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.*;

public class CharacteristicAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Object, Characteristic> {

    private Document doc;

    public CharacteristicAdapter() {
        try {
        doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public Characteristic unmarshal(Object v) throws Exception {
        Element element = (Element) v;
        Characteristic characteristic = new Characteristic();
        characteristic.characteristic = element.getLocalName();
        characteristic.value = element.getTextContent();
        return characteristic;
    }

    @Override
    public Object marshal(Characteristic v) throws Exception {
        Element element = doc.createElement(v.characteristic);
        element.setTextContent(v.value);
        return element;
    }

}
```

### Demo Code

**Demo**

Below is some code that will read/write the desired XML.  Note that the `setAdapter` call on `Marshaller` is not required, but is a performance improvement since it will cause the `XmlAdapter` to be reused.

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Characteristics.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("input.xml");
        Characteristics characteristics = (Characteristics) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setAdapter(new CharacteristicAdapter());
        marshaller.marshal(characteristics, System.out);
    }

}
```

**input.xml/Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<characteristics>
    <store_capacity>40</store_capacity>
    <number_of_doors>4</number_of_doors>
</characteristics>
```