# Dynamic tag value is null when unmarshalling JAXB (based on http://stackoverflow.com/a/26328873/383861)

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

```
package dogs;

@XmlRootElement(name = "dog")
public class Dog extends JAXBElement<String>{

    public static final QName NAME = new QName("dog");

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String dogName;
    private String sound;

    public Dog(String name) {
        super(NAME, String.class, name);
    }

    public Dog(String dogName, String sound) {
        super(NAME, String.class, sound);
        this.dogName = dogName;
    }

    @Override
    public QName getName() {
        final String name = getDogName();
        if(name != null) {
            return new QName(name);
        }

        return NAME;
    }

    public String getDogName() {
        return dogName;
    }

    public void setDogName(String dogName) {
        this.dogName = dogName;
    }

    public String getSound() {
        return sound;
    }

    public void setSound(String sound) {
        this.sound = sound;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Dog [dogName=" + dogName + ", sound=" + sound + "]";
    }
}


package dogs;


@XmlRootElement(name = "listOfDogs")
public class Dogs {

    private List<Object> dogs;

    @XmlMixed
    @XmlAnyElement
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "dogs")
    public List<Object> getDogs() {
        return this.dogs;
    }

    public void setDogs(List<Object> dogs) {
        this.dogs = dogs;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, FileNotFoundException, XMLStreamException {

        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Dogs.class);

        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream("dogs2.xml"));
        xsr = new MyStreamReaderDelegate(xsr);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
        Dogs dogs = (Dogs) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr);
        System.out.println(dogs.getDogs());
    }

    private static class MyStreamReaderDelegate extends StreamReaderDelegate {

        public MyStreamReaderDelegate(XMLStreamReader xsr) {
            super(xsr);
        }

        @Override
        public String getAttributeLocalName(int index) {
            return super.getAttributeLocalName(index);
        }

        @Override
        public String getLocalName() {
            if(super.getLocalName().equals("dog")) {
                try {
                    super.nextTag();
                } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return super.getLocalName();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Dogs [dogs=" + dogs + "]";
    }
}
```

The dogs2.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<listOfDogs>
    <dogs>
        <dog>
            <name>Henry</name>
            <sound>Bark</sound>
        </dog>
    </dogs>
</listOfDogs>
```

The result for the above code is:

```
[[name: null], [sound: null]]
```

But it should be:

```
[Dog [dogName=Henry, sound=Bark]]
```

As you can see, the toString() method from class Dog is not called. I tried overriding getValue() from JAXBElement to return the sound in class Dog but with no result as it was not being called. Nothing from the Dog class is being called when unmarshalling. And instead of List dogs I would prefer to have List dogs so I can get all dogs from a certain index and call getDogName() and getSound(); 
I've read a lot of posts about this topic but I couldn't find something to help me.

Where am I doing wrong? Are there some alternatives?

Comment: I understand this is a continuation of this question but I have no idea how your current example is connected to it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26325201/how-can-i-make-a-class-field-become-a-tag-name-using-jaxb

Also, the method I posted there only works on marshalling, not for unmarshalling.

Comment: @lexicore I wanted to make another simple example for unmarshalling to see how it works.

Comment: Your XML does not seem ti fit your experiment, it does not seem to have dynamic tags. Which tag should be dynamic? `dog`? Right now it is the same in XML and your class. Maybe you could clarify your task or idea on a more abstract level first.

Comment: @lexicore Exactly! The XML input can contain or not dynamic elements. The example I used does not contain dynamic tags.

Comment: Ok. Next question: do we speak a known set of tags or arbitrary? Known set can be defined in ObjectFactory. Arbitrary set is not solveable with this method, I think.

Comment: @lexicore Arbitrary set. But if you know how to solve this with a known set, it's okay for me. :) Thanks!

Comment: I think I have an idea, I'll give it a try in the evening.

Comment: But check this answer first: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26385563/303810 if it is already what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1 - According to your xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<listOfDogs>
    <dogs>
        <dog>
            <name>Henry</name>
            <sound>Bark</sound>
        </dog>
    </dogs>
</listOfDogs>

@XMLRootElement(name="listOfDogs")
class ListOfDogs {

    private Dogs dogs;
    //Getters and Setters

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return dogs + "";
    }

}

@XMLRootElement(name="dogs")
class Dogs {

    List<Dog> dogs;

    @XMLElement(name="dog")
    public List<Dog> getDogs() {
        return dogs;
    }
    //Setters

   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return dogs + "";
   }
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "dog")
public class Dog {

    private String dogName;
    private String sound;

    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    public String getDogName() {
        return dogName;
    }

    public void setDogName(String dogName) {
        this.dogName = dogName;
    }

    public String getSound() {
        return sound;
    }

    public void setSound(String sound) {
        this.sound = sound;
    }

    @Override
     public String toString() {
        return "Dog[" + "dogName=" + dogName + ", sound=" + sound + ']';
     }

}
```

**Solution 2 :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<dogs>
    <dog>
        <name>Henry</name>
        <sound>Bark</sound>
    </dog>
</dogs>
```

With this solution, the ListOfDogs class is no longer utile.you can delete it.

Answer (score 0):

This is NOT an answer, but rather a statement that I could not make it work. I will anyway report as I think it might be a valuable input.

My idea was to implement an `ObjectFactory` with one method per dog name:

```
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    public Dogs createDogs() {
        return new Dogs();
    }

    @XmlElementDecl(name = "dog")
    public Dog createDog(DogType value) {
        return new Dog(value);
    }

    @XmlElementDecl(name = "fido", substitutionHeadName = "dog", substitutionHeadNamespace = "")
    public Dog createFido(DogType value) {
        return new Dog("fido", value);
    }

    @XmlElementDecl(name = "barks", substitutionHeadName = "dog", substitutionHeadNamespace = "")
    public Dog createBarks(DogType value) {
        return new Dog("barks", value);
    }
}
```

I have actually expected that these `createBarks` and `createFido` methods will be called during unmarshalling. This would set the dog name in the `DogType` instance. To be honest, I am surprised that these methods are not called.

However, these methods aren't called during unmarshalling, so I don't get the real tag name.

My idea did not work. If someone wants to experiment, here's my code [here](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/tree/master/runtime/src/test/java/org/hisrc/xml/bind/tests/dogs) and [here](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/tree/master/runtime/src/test/resources/org/hisrc/xml/bind/tests/dogs).

In my test, names aren't set:

```
    @Test
    public void unmarshallsDogs() throws JAXBException {
        final JAXBContext context = JAXBContext
                .newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
        final Dogs dogs = (Dogs) context.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(
                getClass().getResource("dogs.xml"));
        Assert.assertEquals(3, dogs.getDogs().size());
        // Does not work
//      Assert.assertEquals("henry", dogs.getDogs().get(0).getValue()
//              .getName());
        Assert.assertEquals("bark", dogs.getDogs().get(0).getValue().getSound());
        // Does not work
//      Assert.assertEquals("fido", dogs.getDogs().get(1).getValue()
//              .getName());
        Assert.assertEquals("woof", dogs.getDogs().get(1).getValue().getSound());
        // Does not work
//      Assert.assertEquals("barks", dogs.getDogs().get(2).getValue()
//              .getName());
        Assert.assertEquals("miau", dogs.getDogs().get(2).getValue().getSound());
    }
```

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26385563/303810) from Blaise Doughan for an `XmlAdapter`-based solution.